# Filter Custom ListView based on Spinner's selected Item- Not working

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter

I am using a ListView with Custom Adapter(ListItem contains four TextViews). On the same Activity, I have a Spinner. When user selects an item in the Spinner, I want to Filter the ListView based on that selected item (One of those four textviews is the one which is going to be compared with the Spinner's selected Item).

I also have an "All" option in the Spinner which will remove the ListView Filter.

I had been trying that for a long time, but it does not seem to work. What happens is,

- When I select any Item for the First time, I see only the 0th ListItem.
- Consequently, If I select any other item again, ListView has no effect.
- When i select "All", ListView loads all it's Items, and then when I select any Item, it filters as expected. So, each time I had to select "All" and then select the intended item.

Here is the Spinner's ItemSelected event:

```
String[] items = new String[]{"All", "Initiated", "Processing", "Rescheduled", "Completed", "Cancelled"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

        spinnerStatus= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStatus);
        spinnerStatus.setAdapter(adapter);

       spinnerStatus.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               String selectedStatus = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

               if (placedRequestsItemAdapter!=null)
               {
                    placedRequestsItemAdapter.getFilter().filter(selectedStatus, new Filter.FilterListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {

                        }
                    });
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });
```

Here is my Custom Adapter:

```
public class PlacedRequestsItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    List<PlacedRequestItemModel> placedRequests;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;
    List<PlacedRequestItemModel> mStringFilterList;

    public PlacedRequestsItemAdapter(Context context, List<PlacedRequestItemModel> placedRequests) {

        this.context = context;
        this.placedRequests = placedRequests;
        this.mStringFilterList = placedRequests;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return placedRequests.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return placedRequests.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public PlacedRequestItemModel getItem(int position) {
        return placedRequests.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                List<PlacedRequestItemModel> filterList = new ArrayList<PlacedRequestItemModel>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getRequestStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(constraint.toString())) || constraint.toString().equals("All")) {

                        PlacedRequestItemModel listTemp = new PlacedRequestItemModel(mStringFilterList.get(i).getRequestName(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getRequestDate(), mStringFilterList.get(i).getRequestStatus(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getRequestToken());
                        filterList.add(listTemp);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            placedRequests = (ArrayList<PlacedRequestItemModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View listView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            listView = new View(context);
            listView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.placed_requests_item , null);

            TextView tvRequestName = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlacedRequestName);
            tvRequestName.setText(placedRequests.get(position).getRequestName());

            TextView tvRequestDate= (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlacedRequestDate);
            tvRequestDate.setText(placedRequests.get(position).getRequestDate());

            TextView tvRequestStatus= (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlacedRequestStatus);
            tvRequestStatus.setText(placedRequests.get(position).getRequestStatus());

            TextView tvRequestToken = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.tvRequestToken);
            tvRequestToken.setText(placedRequests.get(position).getRequestToken());

        } else {

            listView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return listView;
    }
}
```

Here is the Model class:

```
public class PlacedRequestItemModel
{
    String requestName, requestDate, requestStatus, requestToken;

    public PlacedRequestItemModel(String requestName, String requestDate, String requestStatus, String requestToken) {
        this.requestName = requestName;
        this.requestDate = requestDate;
        this.requestStatus = requestStatus;
        this.requestToken=requestToken;
    }

    public String getRequestDate() {
        return requestDate;
    }

    public void setRequestDate(String requestDate) {
        this.requestDate = requestDate;
    }

    public String getRequestStatus() {
        return requestStatus;
    }

    public void setRequestStatus(String requestStatus) {
        this.requestStatus = requestStatus;
    }

    public String getRequestName() {
        return requestName;
    }

    public void setRequestName(String requestName) {
        this.requestName = requestName;
    }

    public String getRequestToken() {
        return requestToken;
    }

    public void setRequestToken(String requestToken) {
        this.requestToken = requestToken;
    }
}
```

Please guide.

Comment: First change `this.mStringFilterList = placedRequests;` to `this.mStringFilterList = new ArrayList<>(placedRequests);` in `PlacedRequestsItemAdapter` constructor.

Comment: Tried this. No luck!